# FDT and ATAGS support not compiled in resetting ... in ARM Vexpress-A9 board on Qemu machine

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, qemu, u-boot

I am Working on running U-boot using TFTP server on Qemu with vexpress-a9 board.
main goal is to run the Crash dump on Qemu.

using reference pages :

- https://learningfromyoublog.wordpress.com/2016/11/27/u-boot-arm-versatile-express-emulation-on-qemu-with-nfs-as-rootfs/
- https://blog.pentesteracademy.com/booting-an-emulated-arm-device-using-tftp-and-u-boot-6f6868cccd14
- https://imvoid.wordpress.com/tag/booting-uboot-in-qemu/
- https://emreboy.wordpress.com/2012/12/24/connecting-qemu-to-a-real-network/

Part of this page, can load the u-boot successfully,  TFTP is working, Host is alive, can transfer the zImage from Host to target.
When providing  the command to boot the kernel it is giving error message as below & it is resetting the u-boot.

```
> setenv ipaddr 10.0.2.3

=> setenv serverip 10.0.2.15

=> tftp 0x61000000 zImage

smc911x: detected LAN9118 controller

smc911x: phy initialized

smc911x: MAC 52:54:00:12:34:56

Using ethernet@3,02000000 device

TFTP from server 10.0.2.15; our IP address is 10.0.2.3

Filename 'zImage'.

Load address: 0x61000000

Loading: #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     #################################################################

     ############

     3 MiB/s

done

Bytes transferred = 5049424 (4d0c50 hex)

smc911x: MAC 52:54:00:12:34:56

&
for .dtb 

=> tftp 0x61a00000 vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb

smc911x: detected LAN9118 controller

smc911x: phy initialized

smc911x: MAC 52:54:00:12:34:56

Using ethernet@3,02000000 device

TFTP from server 10.0.2.15; our IP address is 10.0.2.3

Filename 'vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb'.

Load address: 0x61a00000

Loading: ###

     1.9 MiB/s

done

Bytes transferred = 14081 (3701 hex)

smc911x: MAC 52:54:00:12:34:56

=> 

when try to boot using bootz cmd 
=> bootz 0x61000000

Kernel image @ 0x61000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x4d0c50 ]

FDT and ATAGS support not compiled in



resetting ...
```

I have gone through same errors from Intel boards, ARM boards (HiKey board from Linaro),
saying as update u-boot & add ENV_VARIABLES in u-boot,
I have changed u-boot release: Prepare v2022.01, but no luck.

Comment: `bootz 0x61000000` only passes the kernel address to the bootz command, but not the FDT. Does `bootz 0x61000000 - 0x61a00000` make any difference?

Comment: Also the error message `FDT and ATAGS support not compiled in` is a bit misleading, as it may appear when FDT support is compiled in, but FDT image address is not passed to the boot* command, see https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/v2022.01/arch/arm/lib/bootm.c#L202

Comment: Hi @jcmvbkbc, thank you for the quick reply, gone through code mentioned in the above message , passed the bootz 0x61000000 - 0x61a00000 , FDT is issue is gone, but it is stopped while decompressing the kernel as below                                              
  => bootz 0x61000000 - 0x61a00000

Kernel image @ 0x61000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x4d0c50 ]

## Flattened Device Tree blob at 61a00000

   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x61a00000

   Loading Device Tree to 7fb20000, end 7fb26700 ... OK



Starting kernel ...


can I  pass uImage instead of zImage?

Comment: Silence after `Starting kernel ...` doesn't necessarily means it is stopped while decompressing, it can be at any later stages if the console is not configured properly in the kernel.

Comment: I believe that you can pass uImage instead of zImage, but you'll have to start it with the `bootm` command instead of `bootz`.

Comment: Hi @jcmvbkbc, thank you for the support, it is working fine now. with Menu config changes in CMDLINE args. & bootz 0x61000000 - 0x61a00000

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

kernel decompression is working fine.
Done changes in Kernel menu config as `CONFIG_CMDLINE="console=ttyAMA0"` & using `bootz 0x61000000 - 0x61a00000`.  It is printing Kernel decompression

```
=> tftp 0x61a00000 vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb

smc911x: detected LAN9118 controller

smc911x: phy initialized

smc911x: MAC 52:54:00:12:34:56

Using ethernet@3,02000000 device

TFTP from server 10.0.2.15; our IP address is 10.0.2.3

Filename 'vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb'.

Load address: 0x61a00000

Loading: ###

     1.3 MiB/s

done

Bytes transferred = 14081 (3701 hex)

smc911x: MAC 52:54:00:12:34:56

=> bootz 0x61000000 - 0x61a00000

Kernel image @ 0x61000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x4d4418 ]

## Flattened Device Tree blob at 61a00000

   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x61a00000

   Loading Device Tree to 7fb20000, end 7fb26700 ... OK



Starting kernel ...



Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0

Linux version 5.15.0 (satishg@satish) (arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Linaro GCC 7.5-2019.12) 7.5.0, GNU ld (Linaro_Binutils-2019.12) 2.28.2.20170706) #4 SMP Tue Mar 21 12:09:42 IST 2023

CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc090] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d

CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache

OF: fdt: Machine model: V2P-CA9

OF: fdt: Ignoring memory block 0x80000000 - 0x80000004

Memory policy: Data cache writeback

Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x4c000000, size 8 MiB

OF: reserved mem: initialized node vram@4c000000, compatible id shared-dma-pool

cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x7e800000

Zone ranges:

  Normal   [mem 0x0000000060000000-0x000000007fffffff]
```

Comment: "*It is printing Kernel decompression*" -- No there is not. Such message would appear between `Starting kernel ...` (by U-Boot) and `Booting Linux on physical CPU ...`, and your log has nothing. You would need to enable CONFIG_DEBUG_UNCOMPRESS (as well as a DEBUG_LL output method) in order to generate the messages `Uncompressing Linux...` and `" done, booting the kernel.`